# Semisimple Lie algebra representation to reductive lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let us work over $\Bbb C$.

If I know the classification of irreducible representations of semisimple Lie algebras, how do I classify the irreducible representations of reductive Lie algebras?

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be reductive, then we can always write $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{s}\oplus \mathfrak{a}$ for $\mathfrak{s}$ a semisimple Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{a}$ an abelian Lie algebra. From this I then just need to choose how $\mathfrak{a}$ act right? So $\mathfrak{s}$ has finite dimensional highest weight irreducible representations classified by the quotients $M(\lambda)$ from the verma modules $V(\lambda)$ where $\lambda \in P^+$ (dominant weights) how does $\mathfrak{a}$ act?

---

Should I be considering the correspondence between $U(\mathfrak{g})$ representations and $\mathfrak{g}$ representations, and then:
$$U(\mathfrak{s}\oplus \mathfrak{a})=U(\mathfrak{s})\otimes U(\mathfrak{a})\cong U(\mathfrak{s})\otimes S(\mathfrak{a})$$
and then how do I find what to quotient by to get all of the finite dimensional irreducible reps?

Comment: It can act in pretty much any way it wants, as long as those actions commute with each other and those from the semisimple part. This will generally leave a lot of possibilities. (Btw, your statement about the simples is not quite right).

Answer (score 2):

If you only want *irreducible* representations (denoted by
$\phi: \mathfrak{g}\to \mathrm{End}(V)$) of a reductive Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, then by Schur's lemma, $\phi(a)=\lambda I$ for $a\in \mathfrak{a}$, where $I$ is the identity map in $\mathrm{End}(V)$. [Note that Schur's lemma works for irreducible representations of arbitrary finite dimensional Lie algebras, provided that the field is algebraically closed.] i.e. the central elements can only act by constant multiplication in irreps.

The real subtlety when it comes to classifying *all* representations of reductive Lie algebras is that there exists *indecomposible* representations that are not irreducible [while for semisimple Lie algebras all representations are completely reducible, so indecomposible and irreducible mean the same thing]. Take $\mathfrak{gl}(2)=\mathfrak{sl}(2)\oplus\mathbb{C}$ for example, spanned by $\{x,y,h,c\}$ where $c$ is the central element. Consider the four dimensional representation
$$x=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0& 1\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0
\end{pmatrix},
y=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0& 0\\
1 & 0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 1& 0
\end{pmatrix},\\
h=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0& 0\\
0 & -1 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 1& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0& -1
\end{pmatrix},
c=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0& 1\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
You can easily show that it is reducible, but indecomposible.